# Conflict in a project due to presence of two green arrows

Tags: java, netbeans, conflict

I am new to Netbeans and trying to piece together my application by using code from different sources. I have a query. In one of my projects there are two different files with green arrows against them - I think the green arrow indicates the presence of a main routine. I want to prioritise which file has the main routine and wanted to know the easiest way to do this. Would this simply be a case of removing the line `public static void main(String args[])` in one of my projects - If not how do I do it. I'm using Netbeans 7.4

Answer (score 0):

Every file with a `main` method will have the *"green arrow"*. Normally, a project should only have one `main` method, the launching point of the program.

You can't change the green arrow in the context your speaking of, but you can change which class is the launching class (Main Class).

1. right click your project.
2. from the context menu select **properties**
3. from the dialog choose **run** on the left.
4. where it says **Main Class** select the class you want as the launching point class.